# How to prevent mouse loading icon during Bootstrap carousel sliding?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootsrap carousel example code in my Magento homepage. The problem is that the mouse icon changes to "aero working" icon every 4 second after adding my own Bootstrap carousel code to the homepage. There are other built-in Bootstrap carousels in the homepage but with different IDs and they don't have this problem. How to fix this problem without disabling auto scrolling?

**Update:** The source of the noise was from another software which tries to connect to the cloud.

```css
.carousel-inner.vertical {
  height: 279px; /*Note: set specific height here if not, there will be some issues with IE browser*/
}

#carousel-pager .carousel-control.left {
 position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
}
#carousel-pager .carousel-control.right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
}
.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 15;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    max-width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 border-radius: 0;
 border: none;

}

.carousel-indicators li::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    content: "";
}

.carousel-indicators li::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    content: "";
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
 margin: 1px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    max-width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}
```

```html
           <div id="carousel-pager" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/234x279/f44336/000000&amp;text=First+Slide" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/234x279/e91e63/000000&amp;text=Second+Slide" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/234x279/9c27b0/000000&amp;text=Third+Slide" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-pager" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-pager" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-pager" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The snippet does not show a working carousel. Can you please add a working demo to help us understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best, but you could try to add a CSS pointer effect onto the carousel:

```
#carousel-pager {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```